# How can I test SonarQube to see how well it actually works for catching security issues in a spring boot app?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, security, sonarqube

We use SonarQube to scan for security vulnerabilities (and other stuff).  I want to know if SonarQube is actually catching important security issues.  I started testing issues 1-by-1 like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // disable csrf
        .csrf().disable()
        // use stateless sessions
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

        // Enable CORS
        .and().cors()
        .and().headers().xssProtection().disable()
        .and().headers().contentTypeOptions().disable()
        .and().headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

Then, I would use SonarQube to scan my code and see if it flagged those security issues that I've introduced.  (for now, I'm only interested in security issues)

The problem is, there are soooo many different vulnerabilities.  What I'm looking for is something like "[Juice shop](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Juice_Shop_Project)" or "[Damn vulnerable web application](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/)".  I want a web app (ideally written in Java Spring boot) that has a ton of security holes in it that I can feed into SonarQube and see what issues it catches and what it doesn't catch.

Does there exist such an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are intentionally vulnerable spring boot apps out there. You can check this one from contrast security. Hopefully it’ll meet your testing needs:

```
https://github.com/Contrast-Security-OSS/vulnerable-spring-boot-application/
```

Comment: Thanks!  However, when I look close at the code of that application, there's not much to it.  I see an SQL injection vulnerability but that's all I see.  I'd like an app with lots of vulnerabilities.

Comment: Something like this might be better then https://github.com/barclayd/Spring-Boot-Cyber-Security/ have seen a few on github over the years but don’t remember where now. You might be able to find more there and Googling. Sorry can’t help you more than that.

Comment: Thanks @Rob-Scully ! That's more what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The "Deliberately insecure web application webgoat 8" looks pretty good as well:

https://www.cyberpunk.rs/deliberately-insecure-web-application-webgoat-8